# I cannot save property of a control in c#

Tags: c#, datagridviewcolumn

I have found this article from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687430/Selecting-Forms-Controls-at-Design-Time

This is written in VB.NET, so I converted into C# version.

And I created a class called "DataGridViewBandColumn" inherits from DataGridViewColumn like below.

```
public class DataGridViewBandColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    private Collection<DataGridViewTextBoxColumn> _TargetControls = new Collection<DataGridViewTextBoxColumn>();

    [EditorAttribute(typeof(BANANA.Windows.Controls.Design.UITypeEditorDropDownCollection), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public Collection<DataGridViewTextBoxColumn> ATargetControls
    {
        get { return _TargetControls; }
        set { _TargetControls = value; }
    }
}
```

I can see the property and select other columns from form design time like below.

[image]

But as soon as I click OK button on property window, it loses the items that I selected and it is not saved on the Form1.Designers.cs file.

Where do I have to check to fix this?

Anyone has any idea?